# redirect root folder to any language folder

Tags: http, redirect, multilingual, http-status-code-301, prestashop-1.7

I have a prestashop site that use to be with only one language.
using this links structure
**mydomain.com/category_name/product_name**
While adding another language to site the links structure has changed to this form
**mydomain.com/en/category_name/product_name**
So when language is switched I get this
**mydomain.com/es/category_name/product_name**

so far so good but
all my old links on search engines redirecting now main page
**mydomain.com/en/**

How can I redirect this so my old links will redirect to the right path to all languages?

I try to redirect root to sub directory and keep the same slug using something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
```